# Nginx rewrite does not change url in the browser

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have nginx config like this:

```
server {
    server_name forum.xyz.pl;
    #return 301 https://forum.xyz.pl$request_uri;
    #rewrite ^ xyz.pl$request_uri? permanent;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://xyz.pl/$1 permanent;
}

server {
  ...

  server_name xyz.pl;
  ...

}
```

Openning forum.xyz.pl in the browsers works but then url in the browser is still old ( still forum.xyz.pl instead of expected xyz.pl ), what should I change there so the user will new url in the browser ?

full config: https://gist.github.com/maciejbak85/c9a50919b606a110bf25a6a9fd950cb2

Comment: Please add more detail, on what you mean by IN BROWSER IT IS SAME, and what do you mean by SAME? Whats old config... all the context please.

Comment: well the same means I still see forum.xyz.pl instead of xyz.pl

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal do you understand now ? Ive edited the post.

Comment: I notice that you redirect from `http` to `https`. Do you have a redirection set up from `https` to `https`? And are you using HSTS headers?

Comment: @RichardSmith this is my full config: https://gist.github.com/maciejbak85/c9a50919b606a110bf25a6a9fd950cb2